# shortcuts run "Maximized" and run "Minimized" don't work?

Tags: windows, windows-vista, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, shortcuts

I've right click -> properties a shortcut icon and i set it to run "Maximized" instead of run "Normal"

However, when i run the shortcut (chrome shortcut) it still opens chrome as "normal" and not maximized..

How do we fix this windows bug?

If this info is required: I'm using 32-bit Widows Vista Home Premium SP2 v6.0.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Right-click the shortcut > **Properties** > **Shortcut** tab > *Target*

After the closing quotes, type a space and enter `-maximized`.

Click OK and try your shortcuts again.

Example:

`"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" -maximized`

Comment: its not working.. in fact when i click OK or Apply, it took away those quotes

Comment: im using windows vista home premium btw

Comment: I see. I'm running Windows 7 Ult. I used to have the same problem with Chrome. When I hit the shortcut, it doesn't open maximized. When I added -maximized, it fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the shortcut pinned to your task bar, you will have to unpin it, then change the properties to maximized, then add it again to your task bar. That should fix it.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Personally, after some testing, I concluded that it doesn't matte whether or not you unpin, then pin again after changing - it worked fine with me for several other applications, just not Chrome.